# Is there an iterator that turns one iteration item into many?

Tags: rust

Contrived example:

```
struct ProduceOnes(Vec<usize>);

impl Iterator for ProduceOnes {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let value = self.0.iter().next()?;

        for _ in 0..*value {
            // I don't want to return, but I want to emit a `Some(1)` for 
            // every iteration of the loop.
            return Some(1);
        }
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to implement a Iterator with `Item=Vec<usize>` instead, but is there an idiomatic alternative for that?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea4943e22c06739fb503667fbe0a246c)

Comment: [`std::iter::repeat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.repeat.html) and [`std::iter::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `flat_map`.

The other tricky part is, that an iterator must keep track of its current element. The idiomatic way to make your example work would probaly be to introduce an `iter` method returing the actual `Iterator`.

```rust
struct ProduceOnes(Vec<usize>);

impl ProduceOnes{

    fn iter<'s>(&'s self) -> impl Iterator<Item=usize> + 's {
        self.0.iter().flat_map(|&value| 0..value).map(|_| 1)
    }
}
```

The resulting iterator will keep track of the current element withouth changing the state of `ProduceOnes`. Could we make your example work without introducing this extra method and implementing the `Iterator` trait directly? The answer is yes, but we need to mutate `ProduceOnes` to do so. Here is an example iterating backwards over the elements in the Vec.

```rust
impl Iterator for ProduceOnes {
    type Item=usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<usize> {
        match self.0.last_mut() {
            Some(&mut 0) => {
                self.0.pop();
                self.next()
            },
            Some(value) => {
                *value -= 1;
                Some(1)
            }
            None => None
        }
    }
}
```